# navigation drawer not showing?

Tags: java, android, navigation, navigation-drawer

Hi I am developing news app using navigation drawer but it is not showing navigation only showing one fragment and I followed this [tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/fragment-navigation-drawer)

[screenshot of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68LR1.png)

below MainActivity.java file

> ```
> public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
>     private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
>     private Toolbar toolbar;
>     private   NavigationView nvDrawer;
>     private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>         // Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar.
>         toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
>         setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
>
>         // Find our drawer view
>         mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
>         drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();
>
>         // Tie DrawerLayout events to the ActionBarToggle
>         mDrawer.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
>
>         nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
>
> // Inflate the header view at runtime
>         View headerLayout = nvDrawer.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header);
> // We can now look up items within the header if needed
>         ImageView ivHeaderPhoto = (ImageView) headerLayout.findViewById((R.id.header_image));
>         setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);
>         FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
>         fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, new BBCSportFragment()).commit();
>         fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, new FoxSportsFragment()).commit();
>         fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, new TalkSportsFragment()).commit();
>
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
>         // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
>         switch (item.getItemId()) {
>             case android.R.id.home:
>                 mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
>                 return true;
>         }
>
>         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
>     }
>
>     private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
>         navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
>                 menuItem -> {
>                     selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
>                     return true;
>                 });
>     }
>
>     public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
>         // Create a new fragment and specify the fragment to show based on nav item clicked
>         Fragment fragment = null;
>         Class fragmentClass = null;
>         switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
>             case R.id.bbcsports_fragment:
>                 fragmentClass = BBCSportFragment.class;
>                 break;
>             case R.id.talksports_fragment:
>                 fragmentClass = TalkSportsFragment.class;
>                 break;
>             case R.id.foxsports_fragment:
>                 fragmentClass = FoxSportsFragment.class;
>                 break;
>             default:
>
>         }
>
>         try {
>             fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
>         } catch (Exception e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>
>         // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
>
>         FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
>         fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
>         // Highlight the selected item has been done by NavigationView
>         menuItem.setChecked(true);
>         // Set action bar title
>         setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
>         // Close the navigation drawer
>         mDrawer.closeDrawers();
>     }
>
>     private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
>         // NOTE: Make sure you pass in a valid toolbar reference.  ActionBarDrawToggle() does not require it
>         // and will not render the hamburger icon without it.
>         return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open,  R.string.drawer_close);
>     }
>
> }
> ```

below activity_main.xml where I have implemented navigation drawer as well as drawer layout.

> ```
> <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent">
>
>     <!-- This LinearLayout represents the contents of the screen  -->
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:orientation="vertical">
>
>         <!-- The ActionBar displayed at the top -->
>         <include
>             layout="@layout/toolbar"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
>
>         <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
>         <FrameLayout
>             android:id="@+id/flContent"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>             app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
>     </LinearLayout>
>
>     <!-- The navigation drawer that comes from the left -->
>     <!-- Note that `android:layout_gravity` needs to be set to 'start' -->
>     <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
>         android:id="@+id/nvView"
>         android:layout_width="240dp"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:layout_gravity="start"
>         android:background="@android:color/white"
>         app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
>         app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />
>
> </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
> ```

below BBCFragment.java

> ```
> public class BBCSportFragment extends Fragment {
>
>     public List<Article> articleList = new ArrayList<Article>();
>     @BindView(R.id.recycler_view)
>     RecyclerView recyclerView;
>     private SportNews sportNews;
>     private ArticleAdapter articleAdapter;
>
>     @Override
>     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
>                              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bbcsport, container, false);
>         ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
>         SportInterface sportInterface = SportClient.getApiService();
>         Call<SportNews> call = sportInterface.getArticles();
>         call.enqueue(new Callback<SportNews>() {
>             @Override
>             public void onResponse(Call<SportNews> call, Response<SportNews> response) {
>                 sportNews = response.body();
>                 if (sportNews != null && sportNews.getArticles() != null) {
>                     articleList.addAll(sportNews.getArticles());
>                 }
>                 articleAdapter = new ArticleAdapter(articleList, sportNews);
>                 RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
>                 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
>                 recyclerView.setAdapter(articleAdapter);
>             }
>
>             @Override
>             public void onFailure(Call<SportNews> call, Throwable t) {
>
>             }
>         });
>
>
>         return view;
>
>
>     }
> }
> ```

below bbc_fragment.xml

> ```
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:orientation="vertical">
>     <!-- The main content view -->
>     <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
>         android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent">
>         <!-- Put what you want as your normal screen in here, you can also choose for a linear layout or any other layout, whatever you
> ```
>
> prefer -->

Comment: just try to make navigationview as first child and then linearlayout as contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override `onPostCreate` and sync the toggle drawer state like this

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
  // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
  drawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

Then you override `onConfigurationChanged` and change toggle drawer configuration

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
  drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Add those two methods and it will work.

Comment: thank you Amine it is working

Comment: I'm glad that you solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
  ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawerLayout, toolbar, "Open navigation drawer", "Close navigation drawer") {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);

            }
        };

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);

        toggle.syncState();

        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```